# How can I enable/ disable the dark theme on a per-site basis in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dark-mode

https://beebom.com/how-enable-disable-dark-theme-per-site-basis-google-chrome/ showed

[image]

but I don't see the option on my side, as I use Microsoft Windows.  How can I enable/ disable the dark theme on a per-site basis in Google Chrome on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: The site you've linked clearly shows and states that the instructions are for android.

Comment: @mashuptwice thanks, how can I enable/ disable the dark theme on a per-site basis in Google Chrome on Windows?

Comment: You could use an extension like [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/)